# String index value access

Tags: java, string, char, charat

This problem is related to String and array in Java. Say I have a String S= abcd. I have an array index[]={2}. My problem is to find out the value from String **S** at its index position 2 because array index[] hold 2. I have a target array which contain "EF". Now if S contain **a** at position 2 then it will  replaced by "EF".

How to access 2 position of S. Is it something like that. `S[index[0]]` Is this return S[2]?

Example:
Input: S = "abcd", indexes = [0,2], sources = ["a","cd"], targets = ["eee","ffff"]
Output: "eeebffff"
Explanation: "a" starts at index 0 in S, so it's replaced by "eee".
"cd" starts at index 2 in S, so it's replaced by "ffff".

Comment: Perhaps `S.charAt(2)` is what you need. You can review the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).

Comment: `S.charAt(index[0])`

Comment: i did not get this `Now if S contain a at position 2 then it will replaced by "EF".`, Explain with clear example with sample input and output

Comment: `S.toCharArray()[index[0]]` (save the `char[]` to a local variable if you need to access it more than once).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch         It throws some error :Error:(17, 21) java: method toCharArray in class java.lang.String cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: I said `S.toCharArray()[index[0]]`, **not** `S.toCharArray([index[0]])` - the first wasn't a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**
After your comment, I added the `sources` array and assuming that both arrays `sources` and `targets` have the same length:

```
    String s = "abcd";
    String[] sources = {"a","cd"};
    int[] indexes  = {0, 2};
    String[] targets = {"eee", "ffff"};

    int more = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
        int startIndex = more + indexes[i];
        int endIndex = more + indexes[i] + sources[i].length();
        if (startIndex < s.length() && endIndex <= s.length()) {
            String sBefore = s.substring(0, indexes[i] + more);
            String sAfter = s.substring(indexes[i] + sources[i].length() + more);
            if (sources[i].equals(s.substring(startIndex, endIndex))) {
                s = sBefore + targets[i] + sAfter;
                more += targets[i].length() - sources[i].length();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(s);
```

will print

```
eeebffff
```

Comment: This code is ok. But `String [] sources` has no trace here. The ckecking should be done deepened upon source string. If the value of `sources` is equal to the value of String `S` at defined position then only String S position value is replaced by the sources values. So I try to modify the code ` String s = ""; for (String n:sources) s+= n;char[] c = s.toCharArray();for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { if(array[indexes[counter]]==c[counter]){result.append(targets[counter]);if(counter<=indexes.length) {
  counter++; }else  result.append(array[i]);}` **Array index outofBound error**

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is to find out the value from String S at its index position 2

`S.charAt(2)` returns a `char` value at its index 2, or you can `char[] charArray=S.toCharArray()` to get a `char[]` and visit it in the array index way like `charArray[2]`

> if S contain a at position 2 then it will replaced by "EF".

```
if(S.charAt(2)=='a'){
   StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(S);
   S=sb.replace(2,3,"EF").toString();
}
```

if you are sure that only one `a` can exists:

```
if(S.charAt(2)=='a'){
     S=S.replace("a","EF");
}
```