# Leetcode 833: String replacement depend upon index numbering

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, stringbuilder

[String index value access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992165/string-index-value-access/53992301#53992301)This question is a part of my previous question .

Example 1:
Input: S = `"abcd"`, indexes = `[0,2]`, sources = `["a","cd"]`, targets = `["eee","ffff"]`
Output: `eeebffff`
Explanation: `a` starts at index 0 in S, so it's replaced by `eee`.
`cd` starts at index 2 in S, so it's replaced by `ffff`.

Example 2:
Input: S = `"abcd"`, indexes = `[0,2]`, sources = `["ab","ec"]`, targets = `["eee","ffff"]`
Output: "eeecd"
Explanation: `"ab"` starts at index 0 in S, so it's replaced by `"eee"`. 
`"ec"` doesn't starts at index 2 in the original S, so we do nothing.

```
public class Q833 {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String S="abcd";
    int[] indexes  = {0, 2};
    String[]sources={"ab","cd"};
    String[] targets = {"eee", "ffff"};
    Solve833 ob833=new Solve833();
    System.out.println(ob833.findReplaceString(S,indexes,sources,targets));
}
}
 class Solve833{
 public String findReplaceString(String S, int[] indexes, String[] sources, String[] targets) {
    char[] array = S.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int counter = 0;
    String s = "";
    for (String n:sources)
        s+= n;
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[indexes[counter]]==c[counter]){
            result.append(targets[counter]);
            if(counter<=indexes.length) {
                counter++;
            }

        }
        else
            result.append(array[i]);
    }


    return result.toString();
}
```

}

**Code Output: for 1st example**

Expected output:`Output: "eeebffff"`.

My output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>     at Leetcode.Solve833.findReplaceString(Q833.java:30)    at
>   Leetcode.Q833.main(Q833.java:16)

**Code Output:2nd example**

Expected Output: `"eeecd"`

My Output: `eeebcd`. So here a b missing. How can I handle it?

Comment: It might help if you add a few sentences about why you are trying to do this.  Is this an abstract homework assignment, or are you trying to solve some real world problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you should NOT do `array[indexes[counter]]==c[counter]` to determine that if the `i-th`source string is presented in the `S` at index `i`. Your juegement only check for the first character of the source string.

The key of this problem is how can we find  the index correctly, as when we are trying to get the result, the index(where to replce the source string with target string) may change.

try this code:

```
  public String findReplaceString(String S, int[] indexes, String[] sources, String[] targets) {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(S);
        int[] offsets=new int[indexes.length];

        for(int i=0;i<indexes.length;i++){

            if(S.substring(indexes[i],indexes[i]+sources[i].length()).equals(sources[i])){
                int offset=0;
                for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                    if(indexes[j]<indexes[i])
                    offset+=offsets[j];
                }
                sb.replace(indexes[i]+offset,indexes[i]+sources[i].length()+offset,targets[i]);
                offsets[i]=targets[i].length()-sources[i].length();

            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method like this to print the result,

```
public class Q833 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String S = "abcd";
        int[] indexes = {0, 2};
        String[] sources = {"a", "cd"};
        String[] targets = {"eee", "ffff"};
        Solve833 ob833 = new Solve833();
        System.out.println(ob833.findReplaceString(S, indexes, sources, targets));
    }
}

class Solve833 {
    public String findReplaceString(String S, int[] indexes, String[] sources, String[] targets) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(S);
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            if (sources[i].equals(result.substring(indexes[i], indexes[i] + sources[i].length()))) {
                result.replace(indexes[i], indexes[i] + sources[i].length(), targets[i]);
                if (i < indexes.length - 1)
                    indexes[i + 1] = indexes[i + 1] + targets[i].length() - sources[i].length();
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```